# Cannot find module error while import using jest in next.js

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js, enzyme

I am trying to configure Jest in my Next.js project. In my test file, I have imported my component like `import { HamburgerMenu } from './HamburgerMenu.jsx'`. In that component, there are so many other imports. Once of them is

```js
import {
  checkValidEmail, getNumbers, getFormttedPhoneNo, validateSubscription,
} from 'helpers/utils';
```

When I run tests, it gives me the following error (which is on above import statement):

```
Cannot find module 'helpers/utils' from 'components/common/Smart/HamburgerMenu/HamburgerMenu.jsx'
```

So here are the details.

`jest.config.js` (at root dir)

```js
module.exports = {
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!**/*.d.ts',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/.next/'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
  },
}
```

I have added `jest: true` in the ESLint file.

`babel.config.js` file (at root dir):

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ["next/babel"],
  plugins: [["babel-plugin-styled-components", { ssr: true }]]
};
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `"./helpers/utils"` instead (relative path)? Using `helper/utils` means that it'll try to match a module, which apparently does not exist.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add

```
...
moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '.'],
...
```

to your `jest.config.js`